# Error while adding @angular/pwa package : Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise. here is how i resolved it for 7.1.4 angular version

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-pwa

Run `ng add @angular/pwa@0.7.4` command in your project directory and all required files for pwa will be added to your root directory:

Comment: It's ok to answer your own questions, but this is not the way to do it. First post a question with a comprehensive description of a problem, and then post an answer beneath. Also, be more concise with the question naming.

Comment: This worked for me.  Thank you